# XML Content is not allowed in prolog DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have this test xml file. I upload it to an amazon web service and the respons is:
XML Content is not allowed in prolog DOM.

I've searched in hex editor, no spaces before, nothing. Could anybody help me?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
      <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A3VK0G8OPY5KRQ</MerchantIdentifier>
        <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
        <Message>
          <MessageID>1</MessageID>
          <Price>
            <SKU>459</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">34.5</StandardPrice>
          </Price>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <MessageID>2</MessageID>
          <Price>
            <SKU>718</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">95</StandardPrice>
          </Price>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <MessageID>3</MessageID>
          <Price>
            <SKU>1007</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">63.25</StandardPrice>
          </Price>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <MessageID>4</MessageID>
          <Price>
            <SKU>3200</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">258.75</StandardPrice>
          </Price>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <MessageID>5</MessageID>
          <Price>
            <SKU>3800</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">166.75</StandardPrice>
          </Price>
        </Message>
      </Header>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is always caused by the invalid XML content in the beginning element. For example, extra small dot “.” in the beginning of XML element.

Any characters before the “

A small dot “.” before the “

```
.<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

To fix it, just delete all those weird characters at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the saving options in your code editor.

the files could be saved as utf-8. The file editor have the option to save in "utf-8" or "utf-8 without BOM" changing to the second option worked out for me... and removed the content before the

I guess you are generating this file with a php script, make sure all the include files are also saved without the BOM (byte order mark)